# Error in Using ShareDialog for Facebook SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I have imported [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) into Eclipse without errors and I am trying to follow the [instructions here to use the ShareDialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android).

Here is the error I see. Not sure where to import the class `Result` from? As you can see the other Facebook SDK Classes have imported fine.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    // this part is optional
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Result result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import:

```
 import com.facebook.share.Sharer;
```

and change your:

```
      @Override
         public void onSuccess(Result result){
```

for

```
      @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

This worked for me

Comment: Thank you - that solved the issue. Will accept as answer in another 2 mins, when SO allows me